# Unstable behavior of Dc-Dc converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, 555, hvdc, lcr

I am currently working on a high voltage boost converter based on Dos4Evers 555 timer based one https://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/flyback.html (12v to 140-220V). I am running into an issue with the output voltage. On start up the output voltage hits ~30V and holds there for a while. After some seemingly random time it then jumps up to 110-130V, finally it will sometimes then jump again up to 280V. I am sometimes able to cause the voltage change by pressing on the components with tweezers or a screwdriver, however it doesn't seem to matter which component I press on. Here is a schematic of the circuit.

[image: Boost Converter Schematic]

I've measured the high side output of the inductor with the scope both when it is sat at 30V and when it is sat at 120V shown below.

[image: boost at 30V]

[image]

I also have a version of this built on a perf board and on a board I made a year ago, they both show the same result on the output (this is working properly at 146V)

[image]

I also tested out the HV side of C5 and the working version has as expected a ripple, however the non working board has no measurable ripple. My first reaction is the non-working board looks like the output of an LCR circuit but I'm not sure what would be causing this (I could also be wrong about that).

Also in case the cause is some silly mistake in my layout, here is the PCB layout.
[image]

Comment: OK now revise your schematic to show the ESR of each e-cap and DCR of L and Ron of FET.   Then you want to add a small Re to NPN to linearize the gain.. then RC feedback then ... .... All these affect Q in your Question

Comment: Have you tried measuring the output of the 555 timer (Q1 gate)?

Comment: @DanielAdamkovič it seems on the working version the duty cycle is about 50% while with the broken version the duty cycle is only ~10%

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 DCR of L is 100mOhms and Ron of the FET is 280mOhms. The caps don't have ESR listed unfortunatly. Also what does adding a small resistor do? (also thanks for the help again)

Comment: If No ESR then it is too high .. Do you know CE gain is Rc/Re?  You better get  simulator or do more reading

Comment: Try removing the Q1 and check the 555 output again. If the PWM isn't correct you have an issue with the circuitry around 555. Could be just something silly like a short or similar. Also, check the divider for Q4 is it correct resistance, don't you have soldering issues around it?

Comment: @DanielAdamkovič The 555 still has the same output without Q1, I double checked all the joints and there are no shorts and everything is properly connected (I also went over it with a hot air rework to really make sure) and I double checked the divider and it's set correctly

Comment: do U have C5 datasheet? or a 10% Dummy load ??  You seem to have excessive RF + CM noise issues . try earth ground with an RF cap.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 this is the data sheet for [C5](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/chara_sheet/C4532X7T2E105M250KA.pdf) I have also used the 0.47uF 400V rated cap from the same series with the same result (although I can't seem to find the part anymore, maybe its no longer produced?)

Comment: Is C3 the correct value? In my simulations, I see similar faults if I make C3 excessively high. I wouldn't worry about C5 at all it has nothing to do with incorrect 555 output even if it wasn't there at all it wouldn't make any difference to the 555's output.

Comment: @DanielAdamkovič  C3 has the correct value and I changed it out for another cap of the same value and still get the same result